# Undefined variable: HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA

Tags: php

when I do a simple echo of $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA i get the error:

```
Undefined variable: HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA
```

I read that in php.ini i need to un-tick

```
always_populate_raw_post_data = On
```

but i still get the error and I did restart Apache as well. Im using php 5.3.6

Comment: Are you using any HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA for any web-service ?

Comment: in this example, no, but i origionally followed this page http://phpmaster.com/web-services-with-php-and-soap-1/   and got the error so i created a single page to investigate the error.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you need to access the raw POST body you should really favor the use of the `php://input` stream over `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` as per the [relevant manual entry](http://us.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php):

> php://input is a read-only stream that allows you to read raw data
>   from the request body. In the case of POST requests, it is preferable
>   to use php://input instead of $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA as it does not
>   depend on special php.ini directives. Moreover, for those cases where
>   $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is not populated by default, it is a potentially
>   less memory intensive alternative to activating
>   always_populate_raw_post_data. php://input is not available with
>   enctype="multipart/form-data".

So, to access the POST body using `php://input`:

```
$post = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Comment: thanks, i did see this when i was reading up on the undefined as well but didnt think to use it. but i was wrong, thanks!

Answer (score 23):

If you get

> Notice: Undefined variable: HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA

Please open your Server file add find

```
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
```

and replace with following 2 lines.

```
if ( !isset( $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA ) ) $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA =file_get_contents( 'php://input' );
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
```

I hope this would help.

Comment: Milap do u have any idea how to get response from a php script, as i used soap service and it is running fine, searched many article and they suggest me to implement ajax, php is server side and i wanted to get response from it so that i can use it in my html form...

Comment: @San http://patelmilap.wordpress.com/2011/09/01/soap-simple-object-access-protocol/
Here i have written simple example. Have a look..