# Why is $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA being called?

Tags: php

I recently upgraded my production server to Ubuntu 14.04 and PHP 5.6, and now I'm getting warnings in my error log:

`2014/10/31 10:42:45 [error] 17128#0: *46238 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Deprecated:  Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead. in Unknown on line 0" while reading response header from upstream, client: 24.123.216.42, server: example.com, request: "POST /api/notes HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/admin/"`

I [read the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php) as well as this somewhat relevant question: [Undefined variable: HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9553168/undefined-variable-http-raw-post-data). However, I can't figure out why this notice is being recorded. As far as I can tell, I'm not using `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` anywhere in my codebase. I've tried:

```
find . -exec grep "HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA" {} \; -print 2>/dev/null
```

from the root directory of my project (including all vendor directories), but I'm not finding any matches.

I [read more about `always_populate_raw_post_data`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.always-populate-raw-post-data) and it appears that `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` should only be populated if the `always_populate_raw_post_data` parameter is set to TRUE. I checked my `phpinfo()` and the parameter is set to 0.

If I'm not explicitly invoking `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` and `always_populate_raw_post_data` is set to `0`, why am I getting these notices in my error log? What does setting `always_populate_raw_post_data` to `-1` do?

Comment: It's possible that it's buried in the server's configuration files.

Comment: I thought about that. I ran a `find /etc/nginx -exec grep "always_populate_raw_post_data" {} \; -print 2>/dev/null` with no results. Also, it's showing up as `0` in `phpinfo()`.

Comment: You know the drill, create minimal code which reproduces the problem.

Comment: Btw. is there a specific reason why you didn't accept my post as answer? I would like to know for future improvements.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning about \`$HTTP\_RAW\_POST\_DATA\` being deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26261001/warning-about-http-raw-post-data-being-deprecated)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's [the relevant C code](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/main/php_content_types.c#populate_raw_post_data) with my comments:

```
static zend_bool populate_raw_post_data(TSRMLS_D)
{
    // not a post, empty request - return FALSE
    if (!SG(request_info).request_body) {
        return (zend_bool) 0;
    }

    // if always_populate_raw_post_data=0 then
    // if we don't know how to parse the post (unknown mimetype) return TRUE
    // otherwise (known mimetype) return FALSE
    if (!PG(always_populate_raw_post_data)) {
        return (zend_bool) !SG(request_info).post_entry;
    }

    // if always_populate_raw_post_data > 0 return TRUE
    // if always_populate_raw_post_data < 0 return FALSE
    return (zend_bool) (PG(always_populate_raw_post_data) > 0);
}
```

That is, setting `always_populate_raw_post_data` to `0` still enables populating for unknown content types. You have to use a negative value to skip it altogether.

This is now [documented](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.always-populate-raw-post-data) in the manual:

> The preferred method for accessing raw POST data is php://input, and $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated in PHP 5.6.0 onwards. Setting always_populate_raw_post_data to -1 will opt into the new behaviour that will be implemented in a future version of PHP, in which $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is never defined.

Comment: I swear that note about setting `auto_populate_raw_post_data` to `-1` wasn't in the docs yesterday!

Comment: Yes, it looks like the note has been added in response to the bug report deW1 mentioned.

Comment: yes it took a while for the docs to update I guess and you weren't lucky enough to check this 1 day later :)

Answer (score 4):

It's already been filed as a [bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67991)

Also read [this](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/slim_post_data).

Basically change the value to `-1` and that'll fix your "problem".

Also make sure you use `php://input` read more below V

> I think it would be better to describe what is actually happening: the
>   E_DEPRECATED will be generated when $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is populated
>   which controlled by the value of always_populate_raw_post_data (link
>   to http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php where we already describe in
>   which case will $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA be populated) and to remove the
>   deprecated message make sure that you don't use $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA
>   but php://input then you can disable the population of
>   $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA via setting always_populate_raw_post_data to -1,
>   which will remove the E_DEPRECATED.

from http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php:

> If set to TRUE, PHP will always populate the $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA
>   containing the raw POST data. Otherwise, the variable is populated
>   only when the MIME type of the data is unrecognised.
>
> The preferred method for accessing raw POST data is php://input, and
>   $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated in PHP 5.6.0 onwards. Setting
>   always_populate_raw_post_data to -1 will opt into the new behaviour
>   that will be implemented in a future version of PHP, in which
>   $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is never defined.

---

Changes to `PHP-5.6`

> Re-usable, optioanlly JITty initialized php://input stream Change
>   always_populate_raw_post_data INI setting to accept three values
>   instead of two.
>
> -1: The behavior of master; don't ever populate $GLOBALS[HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA]
>
> 0/off/whatever: BC behavior (populate if content-type is not
>   registered or request method is other than POST)
>
> 1/on/yes/true: BC behavior (always populate
>   $GLOBALS[HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA])

Comment: Changing the value to -1 does fix the problem.